# Scoping emberjs query params to the controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a route in ember defined as such:

```
this.route('products', { path: '/t' }, function() {
  this.route('index', { path: '/:taxon' });
});
```

So I am able to visit the following URLs:

- /t/shirts
- /t/shoes
- /t/etc...

each of these may have a series of query parameters also. For example I could make a request for red shirts like this `/t/shirts?colour=red`. This is great but I want to persist the query parameters across the controller instance instead of the model. So if I was searching for red shirts and then transitioned to looking at shoes (via a {{#link-to}}) then the query parameters would be available on that route too i.e. `/t/shoes?colour=red`. Currently I don't seem to be able to do this.

I found a reference to something in the ember documentation that states I can set `showMagnifyingGlass`'s scope to "controller" and this will do what I intend but it does not seem to be working. Have I got the wrong end of the stick with `showMagnifyingGlass`? I believe the point of this is scope the query parameters to the controller instance and not the model so that if I were to click on a link that changes the routes model it does not affect the query params.

This is what I have included in my controller:

```
queryParams: [{
  showMagnifyingGlass: {
    scope: 'controller' // Scope the parameters to the controller so transitions share state.
  }
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by, defining your query params on the top-level controller:

**app/products/controller.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['color'],
  color: 'red'
});
```

Then injecting the top-level controller into any other controller:

**app/products/index/controller.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  productsController: Ember.inject.controller('products'),
  color: Ember.computed.reads('productsController.color')
});
```

Then set the top-level query params on the other controller's links:

**app/products/index/template.hbs**

```
{{link-to 'shirts' (query-params color=color)}}
{{link-to 'pants' (query-params color=color)}}
{{link-to 'shoes' (query-params color=color)}}
```

Here's [an ember twiddle of the code above in action](https://ember-twiddle.com/ce67c59795e24a1a16e4?numColumns=1&openFiles=products.index.controller.js%2C&route=%2Ft%2Fshirts%3Fcolor%3Dblue) and [more info on injecting controllers](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/) into each other.

Comment: Not sure whether this is quite what I am looking for. The items names (i.e. shirts, pants, shoes) are dynamic segments and are therefore transitioned to with `{{#link-to 'products' 'shirts' (query-params colour=colour)}}`. Would this solution still work in this case?

Comment: I've updated the twiddle to accommodate the routes you have!

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks